# Web page /method to convert Degrees, Minutes and Seconds to Decimal degrees

Tags: conversion, web

I need a web page, software or any other method where I can provide a list (of about 10000) location points in D°M'S"  (latitude and longitude) and get the equivalent value in decimal degrees (e.g., 132.123456 lat,  99.12345 long).

All the web pages and methods I have seen require to insert the data one by one. And a method provided by MSDN ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213449 ) gives completely wrong results.

The required format for input does not matter as I can easily modify the data to comply with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a windows machine then you may already have (or can easily get) Windows Powershell. Given a CSV file named Info.csv with contents like this:

```
Lat, Long
56 35 42, 73 55 21
12 55 12, 155 23 42
```

This would produce the conversion as long as I got the formula right off wiki:

```
Import-csv C:\Path\To\Info.csv | Select @{n='Lat'; e={[int[]]$p = $_.Lat.Split(' '); $res = $p[0] + ($p[1]/60) + ($p[2]/3600); return "{0:N6}" -f $res}}, @{n='Long'; e={[int[]]$p = $_.Long.Split(' '); $res = $p[0] + ($p[1]/60) + ($p[2]/3600); return "{0:N6}" -f $res}}
```

Which gives a result like this:

```
Lat                                                         Long
---                                                         ----
56.595000                                                   73.922500
12.920000                                                   155.395000
```

To behonest though, you should probably write it out as a script and do all the good things that you should always do anyway like data validation.

Comment: I will also point out that this is written to just handle positive latitudes. You would need to tweak it for the southern hemisphere. :)

Comment: Well, your answer is the one that approaches what I want the most... Except that as you say I *need* to consider negative latitudes (southern hemisphere coordinates). As I have no experience in GIS, I really do not know what changes to do to your script. :(

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like exactly the kind of problem that [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) was created for.

There's also an open source alternative to matlab called [freemat](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/) that you can try. There are [additional alternatives listed here](http://www.morlok.net/ryan/2006/11/01/open-source-matlab-alternatives/).

EDIT: Here's some additional help with matlab:

- [MatLab Introductory Notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-094-introduction-to-matlab-january-iap-2010/lecture-notes/)
- [Matlab examples](http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/matlab-examples.html)
- [file input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html)

Comment: I was thinking MATLAB might be a good solution as well. Could you edit your answer to provide a bit more info about how MATLAB could be used to do this computation (i.e. if it has a built in function for it or if you'd have to write your own, etc.)

Comment: @nhinkle - I don't know the algorithm he wants to implement, makes it harder. I'm just providing a pointer in the direction I'd be going.

Comment: Good advice, unfortunately my problem is of the  "one shot" type. I only need to transform these coordinates. I cannot really proceed to download and install a new application just for this. In addition, as nhinkle has said, you did not provide any solution to my main questions. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @obaqueiro - I see, I didn't understand that you were looking for an algorithm more than anything..

Answer (score 0):

Could you make use of the open source software: [proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) ?

If you scroll to the bottom of that page to the section **Other projections libraries/sofware** you might find of interest:

- [Proj4js](http://www.proj4js.org/) (a javascript library that uses proj4)
- [proj4php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proj4php/) (php based library using proj4)
- [Geotools](http://geotools.org/) ?

*Docs and other information:*

- [General Parameters](http://proj.maptools.org/gen_parms.html)
- [proj4 man page](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_proj)
- [cs2cs man page](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs)
- [Cartographic Projection Procedures for the UNIX Environment — A User’s Manual by Gerald I. Evende](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/proj/OF90-284.pdf) (2.7MB, PDF)

Proj4 can read input from stdin or a redirection so batch processing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Mapsdata online converter might work for you:
http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/online-file-converter/

> Our free online converters let you batch geocode ZIP codes and UK
>   postcodes, convert GPX to KML, SHP to KML and KMZ to KML, convert UTM
>   to lat lon, and much, much more… We developed the technologies behind
>   these converters for our own products and decided to share them for
>   others to use freely. There is currently no limit to the number of
>   entries you can convert, aside from how much our servers can take, so
>   enjoy! And if we helped, let us know on Twitter: @Mapsdata or via
>   email.

unfortunately they don't seem to go back the other way, from decimal degrees to degrees minutes seconds